# Remove elements from a list in karate?

Tags: karate

after using scripAll() to get list of style attribute values, I need to eliminate a few. Wanted to know if there is something like remove() in python which can be used for the same.

Example:
`*  def list_colors = ["rgb(245,60,86)", "rgb(245,60,86)", "rgb(245,00,00)", "rgb(245,00,00)" ]`

Want to remove rgb(245,00,00) from the list. How can I do this in karate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed that `scriptAll()` can take a third "filter function" argument, please refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#scriptall-with-filter

```
* def list_colors = scriptAll('.my-css', "_.style['display']", x => !x.includes('245,00,00'))
```

Otherwise please refer JSON transforms: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

```
* def filtered = karate.map(list_colors, x => !x.includes('245,00,00'))
```